# FUSE ESB 6.0 bundle start error: Bundle xxx is waiting for namespace handlers [http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth]

Tags: spring, oauth, spring-security, fuseesb, blueprint

Fuse 2.3.0.redhat-60024 and Spring Namespaces

I am trying to develop a solution using fuse that using the Spring implementation of oauth1 (mvn:org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth/1.0.5.RELEASE). This spring bundle seems to have the best client side support that I have found and I already have it implemented in spring (running in tomcat), but not in Fuse.

The namespace and schema location for the spring bundle is:
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth-1.0.xsd

However, when I use this namespace in the blueprint.xml file, and install the bundle, the bundle is not started. On the console, "GracePeriod" is shown. In the log, I get the following:

17:23:44,490 | INFO  | NAPSHOT-thread-1 | BlueprintContainerImpl           | 14 - org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.0.1.redhat-60024 | Bundle com.transverse.tract.connect.tc-core-auth-oauth is waiting for namespace handlers [[http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth]](http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth%5d)

I have tried many solutions, but none allow the oauth namespace class to be registered or linked to the OSGi service, and I always get this message.

Please give me some pointers. I have included the blueprint file below. Let me know if you need anything else.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0"
    xmlns:ext="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.1.0"
    xmlns:oauth1="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
        http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-cm/blueprint-cm-1.1.0.xsd
        http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-ext/v1.1.0 http://aries.apache.org/schemas/blueprint-ext/blueprint-ext-1.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth-1.0.xsd">
    <ext:property-placeholder placeholder-prefix="${[" placeholder-suffix="]}"/>

    <!--  
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

    <sec:debug/>
    <sec:http auto-config="true" security="none" pattern="/**"/>

    <ctx:spring-configured/>
    <ctx:annotation-config/>
    -->
    <bean id="protectedResourceDetailsService" class="org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.InMemoryProtectedResourceDetailsService"/>
    <bean id="oauthConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.oauth.consumer.client.CoreOAuthConsumerSupport"/>

    <oauth1:consumer resource-details-service-ref="tcOAuth10aResourceDetails" support-ref="oauthConsumer">
        <oauth1:url pattern="cxf/oauth/request_token" resources="oauthProvider" httpMethod="GET"/>
        <oauth1:url pattern="cxf/oauth/access_token" resources="oauthProvider" httpMethod="GET"/>
    </oauth1:consumer>


    <oauth1:consumer-details-service id="tcOAuth10aConsumerDetails">
        <oauth1:consumer name="oauthConsumerDetails"
                        resourceName="oauthProvider"
                        key="..."
                        secret="..."
                        requiredToObtainAuthenticatedToken="true"
                        typeOfSecret="shared"
                        resourceDescription="OAuth"/>
    </oauth1:consumer-details-service>
    <oauth1:resource-details-service id="tcOAuth10aResourceDetails">
        <oauth1:resource id="quickbooksOnlineProvider"
                        key="..."
                        secret="..."
                        user-authorization-callback-param="oauth_callback"
                        user-authorization-token-param="requestToken"
                        request-token-url="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_request_token"
                        user-authorization-url="https://appcenter.intuit.com/Connect/Begin"
                        access-token-url="https://oauth.intuit.com/oauth/v1/get_access_token"
                        signature-method="HMAC-SHA1"
                        accepts-authorization-header="true"
                        use10a="true"
                        access-token-method="POST"
                        request-token-method="POST"/>
    </oauth1:resource-details-service>
</blueprint>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure about that as I never used OAuth in FUSE. But, it seems that there is no Spring OAuth OSGI feature installed in your FUSE installation. Did you check if the Spring OAuth library is OSGI enabled and if a Spring OAuth OSGI feature exits at all? If there is such a feature, you may verify with `features:list | grep oauth` if it is correctly installed in your FUSE installation.

If the Spring OAuth library is not OSGI-fied, then you may use the CXF-RS implemenation. See [here](http://fusesource.com/docs/mirrors/cxf/index/restful-services/jax-rs/jax-rs-oauth2.html) how this can be done.